# Show the integral equality $\int_0^{k} x(k-x) \,\mathrm{d}x =1/2 \int_{0}^k x^2 \,\mathrm{d}x$ without direct computation

Tags: definite-integrals, substitution, symmetry

Is it possible to prove that

$$\int_0^{k} x(k-x) \,\mathrm{d}x =\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^k x^2 \,\mathrm{d}x$$

*without* directly computing the right hand side, left hand side and see that they are equal? I can simply evaluate it as follows, but that is *not* what I am asking =)

$$
     \int_0^{k} x(k-x) \mathrm{d}x
   = \Bigl[\frac{k}{2}\cdot x^2 - \frac{1}{3}\cdot x^3\Bigr]_0^k
   = \frac{k}{2}k^2 - \frac{1}{3}k^3  
   = \frac{k^3}{2} - \frac{k^3}{3}
   = \frac{k^3}{6}
         = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^k x^2 \mathrm{d}x
$$

Is there some symmetry argument or substitution that could be made?
I already know that

$$
\int_0^{k} x(k-x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{k/2} x(k-x)\,\mathrm{d}x
= \frac{1}{2} \int_{k/2}^k x(k-x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

I also attempted a few substitutions such as $x=k/2-y$ without much success.

Comment: Leibniz rule? You obtain
$$ \int_0^k x \ dx = \frac{k^2}{2} $$

Comment: If you allow manipulations, this is equivalent to asking why $$ k \int_0^k x\, dx = \frac{3}{2} \int_0^k x^2\,dx.$$ Perhaps there's a good argument for this (without computation and using symmetry or geometric arguments instead). This reminds me a bit of harmonic oscillator energy equations but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integration by parts:
$$
\int_0^{k} x(k-x) \, dx = \underbrace{ \left[ (\frac 12 x^2)(k-x)\right]_{x=0}^{x=k}}_{= 0}- \int_0^{k} (\frac 12 x^2) (-1) \, dx
$$

As a small generalization you can prove (using repeated integration by parts) that
$$
\int_0^{k} x^p(k-x)^q \, dx = \frac{p! q!}{(p+q)!}\int_0^{k} x^{p+q} \, dx 
$$
for positive integers $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Clever! I will wait a bit to accept the answer to see if alternative solutions comes in.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar you're not going to get a simpler answer than this. If you'd like some complex discussion about energy it will ultimately boil back down to this computation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Take derivatives; you'll get $x^2/2=x^2/2$, hence both integrals differ only by a constant.  Now substitute $k=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^{k} x(k-x) \,\mathrm{d}x =\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^k x^2 \,\mathrm{d}x\iff$$
$$\int_0^{k} 3x^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^k 2kx \,\mathrm{d}x \stackrel{x=ku}{\iff}$$
$$\int_0^1 3u^2\,\mathrm{d}u =\int_0^12u\,\mathrm{d}u$$
On the other hand,
$$\int_0^1 3u^2\,\mathrm{d}u\stackrel{u=v^{1/3}}{=}\int_0^1dv$$
and
$$\int_0^1 2u\,\mathrm{d}u\stackrel{u=v^{1/2}}{=}\int_0^1dv.$$